# QPrinter margins under Py3 and PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, margins, qprinter

I am updating my program under Python3 and PyQt5, I use QPrinter to associate different small texts (and also images) in a single PDF document. The Python2 and PyQt4 version of the program works well, but by passing it under PyQt5 (and QPrinter) I have a problem with the margins (they are much too wide afterwards); it seems that setPageMargins is not working well (at least not as well as in QPrinter's PyQt4 version). I wrote a little script inspired by the one present in my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

class Html_vers_pdf_fiche_eleve(QPrinter):
    def __init__(self, niv_de_classe, nbre_seances, titre_prog, num_seq, incitation, demande, vocabulaire, questions, texte_ref_art_1, texte_ref_art_2, texte_ref_art_3, vignette_img_src_1, vignette_img_src_2, vignette_img_src_3, marge_gauche, marge_haute, marge_droite, marge_basse, police_normaux_caracteres, police_petits_caracteres):
        super(Html_vers_pdf_fiche_eleve, self).__init__(QPrinter.HighResolution)

        # Rubriques ...
        variable_001 = "Classe :"
        variable_002 = "Date :"
        variable_003 = "Durée :"
        variable_004 = "Nom :"
        variable_005 = "Prénom :"
        variable_006 = "Titre de la progression :"
        variable_007 = "Séquence n° :"
        variable_008 = "Incitation :"
        variable_009 = "Demande :"
        variable_010 = "Vocabulaire :"
        variable_011 = "Questions (répondre derrière cette feuille) EVENTUELLEMENT ECRIRE UN COMMENTAIRE :"
        variable_012 = ''
        variable_014 = "Travaux d'artistes (références) :"
        variable_015 = "Les élèves, évaluez vontre travail en utilisant les smileys juste en dessous de Eval Elève"
        variable_016 = "Eval Elève"
        variable_017 = "Evaluation Professeur"
        variable_018 = "Ci-dessous se trouvent les critères d'évaluation des compétences travaillées en arts plastiques"

        # HTML ; écriture de l'entête
        html_entete = '''<html><head><title></title>'''+'''\n'''+'''<style type="text/css">'''+'''\n'''+'''table { border-style:solid;border-width:1.3px;border-color:#3c3c3c;font-size:'''+str(police_normaux_caracteres)+'''pt;font-family: "DejaVu Sans, sans-serif" }'''+'''\n'''+'''</style>'''+'''\n'''+'''</head>'''+'''\n'''+'''<body>'''+'''\n'''

        # HTML ; écriture du niveau de classe, de la date et de la durée
        html_tab_ligne_0 = '''<table width="100%" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0.5">'''+'''\n'''+'''<tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="22%"><p><b>'''+str(variable_001)+''' '''+str(niv_de_classe)+'''ème</b></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="35%"><p><b>'''+str(variable_002)+'''</b></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="43%"><p><b>'''+str(variable_003)+''' '''+nbre_seances+'''</b></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''</tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''</table>'''+'''\n'''

        # HTML ; écriture du nom et du prénom
        html_tab_ligne_1 = '''<table width="100%" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0.5">'''+'''\n'''+'''<tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="50%"><p><b>'''+str(variable_004)+'''</b></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="50%"><p><b>'''+str(variable_005)+'''</b></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''</tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''</table>'''+'''\n'''

        # HTML ; écriture du titre de la progression et du numéro de la séquence
        html_tab_ligne_2 = '''<table width="100%" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0.6">'''+'''\n'''+'''<tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="83%"><p><b><u>'''+str(variable_006)+'''</u>'''+''' '''+titre_prog+'''</b></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="17%"><p><u><b>'''+str(variable_007)+'''</u>'''+''' <b>'''+str(num_seq)+'''</b></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''</tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''</table>'''+'''\n'''

        # HTML ; écriture de l'incitation
        html_tab_ligne_3 = '''<table width="100%" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0.5">'''+'''\n'''+'''<tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="100%" bgcolor="#e1dede"><p><b><u>'''+str(variable_008)+'''</u>'''+''' '''+incitation+'''</b></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''</tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''</table>'''+'''\n'''

        # HTML ; écriture de la demande
        html_tab_ligne_4 = '''<table width="100%" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0.6">'''+'''\n'''+'''<tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="100%" bgcolor="#e1dede"><p><b><u>'''+str(variable_009)+'''</u></b>'''+''' '''+demande+'''</p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''</tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''</table>'''+'''\n'''

        # HTML ; écriture de l'entête de la liste des mots de vocabulaire
        html_tab_ligne_5 = '''<table width="100%" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0.5" bgcolor="#cccccc">'''+'''\n'''+'''<tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="100%"><p><b><u>'''+str(variable_010)+'''</u></b></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''</tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''</table>'''+'''\n'''

        # HTML ; écriture de la liste des mots de vocabulaire
        html_tab_ligne_6 = '''<table width="100%" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0.5">'''+'''\n'''+'''<tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="100%"><p>'''+vocabulaire+'''</p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''</tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''</table>'''+'''\n'''

        # HTML ; écriture de l'entête des questions posées aux élèves
        html_tab_ligne_7 = '''<table width="100%" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0.5" bgcolor="#cccccc">'''+'''\n'''+'''<tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="100%"><p><u><b>'''+str(variable_011)+'''</b></u></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''</tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''</table>'''+'''\n'''

        # HTML ; écriture des questions posées aux élèves
        html_tab_ligne_8 = '''<table width="100%" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0.5">'''+'''\n'''+'''<tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="100%"><p><b>'''+questions+'''</b></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''</tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''</table>'''+'''\n'''

        # HTML ; écriture de l'entête Travaux d'artistes (références)
        html_tab_ligne_9 = '''<table width="100%" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0.5" bgcolor="#cccccc">'''+'''\n'''+'''<tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="100%"><p><u><b>'''+str(variable_014)+'''</b></u></p></td>'''+'''\n'''+'''</tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''</table>'''+'''\n'''
        #html_tab_ligne_9 = html_tab_ligne_9.decode('utf-8')

        # HTML ; écriture du nom de l'artiste, de l'oeuvre, d'un résumé et des vignettes correspondantes
        html_tab_ligne_10 = '''<table width="100%" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0.5">'''+'''\n'''+'''<tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="33%"><font color="#000000" size="'''+str(police_petits_caracteres)+'''" family="DejaVu Sans, sans-serif"><b>'''+texte_ref_art_1+'''</b></font><br />'''+'''<div align="center">'''+vignette_img_src_1+'''</div><p />'''+'''</td>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="33%"><font color="#000000" size="'''+str(police_petits_caracteres)+'''" family="DejaVu Sans, sans-serif"><b>'''+texte_ref_art_2+'''</b></font><br />'''+'''<div align="center">'''+vignette_img_src_2+'''</div><p />'''+'''</td>'''+'''\n'''+'''<td width="34%"><font color="#000000" size="'''+str(police_petits_caracteres)+'''" family="DejaVu Sans, sans-serif"><b>'''+texte_ref_art_3+'''</b></font><br />'''+'''<div align="center">'''+vignette_img_src_3+'''</div><p />'''+'''</td>'''+'''\n'''+'''</tr>'''+'''\n'''+'''</table>'''+'''\n'''

        # HTML ; écriture de la fin de la page
        html_body_html_final = '''</body></html>'''

        #
        self.doc = QTextDocument()

        # Ecriture de la syntaxe HTML finale
        self.doc.setHtml(html_entete + html_tab_ligne_0 + html_tab_ligne_1 + html_tab_ligne_2 + html_tab_ligne_3 + html_tab_ligne_4 + html_tab_ligne_5 + html_tab_ligne_6 + html_tab_ligne_7 + html_tab_ligne_8 + html_tab_ligne_9 + html_tab_ligne_10 + html_body_html_final)

        # Ecriture du fichier PDF par QPrinter
        self.printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        self.printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        self.printer.setOrientation(QPrinter.Portrait)
        self.printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter.A4)
        # La taille des marges est convertie en millimètres
        self.printer.setPageMargins(int(marge_gauche*10), int(marge_haute*10), int(marge_droite*10),  int(marge_basse*10), QPrinter.Millimeter)

        print("Le fichier pdf a été crée !")
        self.printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf")

        # Ecriture finale du fichier PDF
        self.doc.print_(self.printer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #############################################
    # Pictures (3 pictures)
    img_ref_art_1 = os.path.expanduser('~')+os.sep+"college/cours/Cours_Travaux_a_faire__COLLEGE_NOUVEAUX_PROGRAMMES/Niveau_3eme_cycle_4/sequence_eleve/tom_wesselmann_still_life_20_vue_01.jpg"
    img_ref_art_2 = os.path.expanduser('~')+os.sep+"college/cours/Cours_Travaux_a_faire__COLLEGE_NOUVEAUX_PROGRAMMES/Niveau_3eme_cycle_4/sequence_eleve/georges_melies_le_voyage_ds_la_lune_1902.png"
    img_ref_art_3 = os.path.expanduser('~')+os.sep+"college/cours/Cours_Travaux_a_faire__COLLEGE_NOUVEAUX_PROGRAMMES/Niveau_3eme_cycle_4/sequence_eleve/louise_nevelson_sky_cathedral_bois_peint_en_noir_1958.png"
    # (Réglages) Valeurs des marges
    marge_gauche = 0.00 # marge en cm
    marge_droite = 0.00 # marge en cm
    marge_haute = 0.00 # marge en cm
    marge_basse = 0.00 # marge en cm
    # (Réglages) Taille de la police
    # ------------------------------------------
    # Texte partie générale (taille de la police)
    taille_police_texte_general = 8 # (valeurs entre 6 et 10, 8 par défaut)
    # Texte travaux d'artistes et évaluation (taille de la police)
    taille_police_trav_artist = 2 # (valeurs 1 ou 2, 2 par défaut)
    liste_vocab = ['<b><u>Mot de vocabulaire 1 :</u></b> La définition du mot de vocabulaire 1 ... '+'bla bla blablablabla '*10+'<br />', '<b><u>Mot de vocabulaire 2 :</u></b> La définition du mot de vocabulaire 2.<br />', '<b><u>Mot de vocabulaire 3 :</u></b> La définition du mot de vocabulaire 3 ...'+'bla bla blablablabla '*14+'<br />', '<b><u>Mot de vocabulaire 4 :</u></b> La définition du mot de vocabulaire 4 ...'+'bla bla blablablabla '*17+'<br />', '<b><u>Mot de vocabulaire 5 :</u></b> La définition du mot de vocabulaire 5.<br />', '<b><u>Mot de vocabulaire 6 :</u></b> La définition du mot de vocabulaire 6.<br />', '<b><u>Mot de vocabulaire 7 :</u></b> La définition du mot de vocabulaire 7 ...'+'bla bla blablablabla '*5+'<br />', '<b><u>Mot de vocabulaire 8 :</u></b> La définition du mot de vocabulaire 8.']
    liste_questions = ["1) Est-ce que QPrinter est intéressant ?, ... oui en fait.<br />", "2) Est-ce que c'est facile à manipuler ?, ... oui quand on a compris comment ça fonctionne.<br />", "3) Est-ce que QPrinter est pratique ?, ... oui oui !, dans mon cas pour faire quelque chose en full Python, sans devoir appeler (et embarquer) un programme tiers."]
    liste_textes_art = ['''* Tom Wesselmann, "Still Life 20" (1962). Résumé du contexte de l'oeuvre ... '''+"bla bla blablablabla "*16, '''* Georges Meliès, "Le voyage dans la lune" (1902). Résumé du contexte de l'oeuvre ...'''+"bla bla blablablabla "*18, '''* Louise Nevelson, "Sky cathedral" (1958) ... bois peint en noir ...'''+"bla bla blablablabla "*10]
    liste_img_src_ref_art = ['''<img src="'''+img_ref_art_1+'''"'''+''' width="150" height="146" />''', '''<img src="'''+img_ref_art_2+'''"'''+''' width="150" height="100" />''', '''<img src="'''+img_ref_art_3+'''"'''+''' width="150" height="109" />''']
    #############################################
    # Appel de la classe
    Html_vers_pdf_fiche_eleve(3, "2 à 3 séances", "&quot; Une progression avec un titre &quot;", 1, "&quot; Une incitation qui n'en dit pas trop ! &quot;", "La demande est faite pour faire en sorte que l'élève comprenne un peu plus ce qu'il y a à faire mais en même temps cette demande ne lui donne pas trop de pistes de travail afin que la situation problème (énoncée par l'incitation) soit tout de même présente."+" Blabla blablabla "+"blablabla blabla"*32, ''.join(liste_vocab), ''.join(liste_questions), liste_textes_art[0], liste_textes_art[1], liste_textes_art[2], liste_img_src_ref_art[0], liste_img_src_ref_art[1], liste_img_src_ref_art[2], marge_gauche, marge_haute, marge_droite, marge_basse, taille_police_texte_general, taille_police_trav_artist)
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

Maybe it's a PyQt5 bug at this level, or has the syntax for using QPrinter changed in margin management?

My version of Python: 3.4.3 and my version of PyQt5: 5.2.1.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Is this actually a bug ?

--> https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32987

Comment: Possibly. What platform(s) are you testing on?

Comment: toto@toto-kubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux toto-kubuntu 3.19.0-71-generic #79~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 8 20:07:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: It might help if you could provide the *simplest possible example* that still reproduces the problem. It should be possible to do that with no more than about twenty lines of code. You should also try to test with the latest versions of both qt and pyqt. The version of pyqt you are using is *over four years old*, and I assume your qt version must be of a similarly ancient vintage.